# How batch edit contents of near 2000 field values in MariaDB table?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would need to edit and change the content for around 2000 field values in my database "alyssa" for "products" table and for all its field of "productId".

Every productId is in numeric format "1234567890".
I would need to change all of these numeric id's to conform the following format:
"alyssa-PROD-1234567890-1".

So, e.g. if the product id was like "3298374237" it would need to be changed to the format of "alyssa-PROD-3298374237-1".

The fixed values are "alyssa-PROD-" and tailing "-1". These won't be changing.

Please could you possibly kindly assist me to form a script / command which I could run in order to batch change all of the productId's to the described format?

Thank you so much in advance! :) Yours, Alyssa

Comment: Note, your table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ as properly formatted tabular text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update`:

```
update t
    set productId = concat('alyssa-PROD-', productId, '-1');
```

Note:  This assumes that `productId` is stored as a string, albeit a string consisting only of digits.  If you only want numeric strings to be converted:

```
update t
    set productId = concat('alyssa-PROD-', productId, '-1')
    where productId regexp '^[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: `concat('alyssa-PROD-', cast(productId as char), '-1')` in case productId has a numeric column type.

Comment: @GeorgRichter . . . The explicit conversion is not necessary.